# Python / read a specific part in a log file

Tags: python

I have a `.log` file in python. For example:

```
**** start logging ****
line 1
line 2
line 3
**** end logging ****
**** start logging ****
line 4
line 5
line 6
**** end logging ****
```

I want to read and print only the last logging of this file (when `**** start logging ****` is written). In our case:

```
**** start logging ****
line 4
line 5
line 6
**** end logging ****
```

As I know. the `.read()` and `.seek()` functions in python should be sufficient for this mission. But as I see, `seek()` only get offset, not a string variable.

How can I take only a specific part in this `.log` file?

Comment: did you think about regrex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to split your file with `**** start logging ****` and then add it again to last element of split list !

```
with open('new.txt' ,'r') as f :
    lines=f.read()
    print "**** start logging ****"+ lines.split("**** start logging ****")[-1]
```

result :

```
**** start logging ****
line 4
line 5
line 6
**** end logging ****
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

**Demo**

```
>>> content = '''**** start logging ****
... line 1
... line 2
... line 3
... **** end logging ****
... **** start logging ****
... line 4
... line 5
... line 6
... **** end logging ****'''
>>> ''.join(content.split('**** start logging ****')).replace('**** end logging ****','')
'\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3\n\n\nline 4\nline 5\nline 6\n'
```

Comment: It'll be heavy on memory if the logfile is big, as your method requires the contents of the entire log file to be read at once.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the entire file.

```
with open(logfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('**** start logging'):
            l = []
        else:
            l.append(line)
print('\n'.join(l[:-1]))
```

The last entry in l will be the line `end logging`, so I explicitly remove it.

Alternatively, you could use `file.seek(n, -2)`, where `n` is a guess for how many characters each logging record is, but then you would still have to perform some iteration to get the entire record, and check that there is only one instance of the phrase 'start logging' in it, which means you'll execute the code above anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You speak of read and seek so I suppose you do not want to keep a full bunch of lines in memory. You can simply store the position of last logging start and rewind there :

```
with open(logfile) as fd:
    last_log_start = None
    while True:
        line = fd.readline()
        if line is None: break
        if line.startswith('**** start logging'):
            last_log_start = fd.tell()
    if last_log_start is not None:
        fd.seek(last_log_start)
        while True:
            line = fd.readline()
            if line is None: break
            if line.startswith('**** end logging'): break
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```